# call function inside method from external js

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval, external-js

Please bear with me since I am a newbie in JS programming.

I have the following problem:

One of my modules contains a setInterval loop.
This module is called by my `server.js` when an HTML button is clicked (ON, variable state in the code). I would like to interrupt its execution (OFF) from the `server.js` but it doesn't work..

I know it feels like a duplicate question, but I have searched a lot for the info inside Stack Overflow and all questions refer to code being executed and stopped from within the same file. In my case, I am calling a  method in an external file (which contains the `setInterval`) and I want to trigger `clearInterval` which should be ran in that external file!

Simplified code below:

**action.js**

```
module.a = function(milisec) {
    var myVar = setInterval( function() { do stuff }, milisec);
}
module.exports = methods;
```

My first attempt:

**Server.js**

```
// var state is a button on my HTML
var actions = require('./actions');
If (state == 1)
{ actions.a(milisec) }
If (state == 0)
{ clearInterval(myVar) }
```

But it didn't work. And I think it's also clear why: The code has no clue where I got the `myVar` from, basically I think I should call a function from inside the module to stop the `setInterval`, therefore, I included the function `stop()` in the method.

My second attempt:

**action.js**

```
methods.a = fuction(milisec) {
    var myVar = setInterval( function() { 
    console.log("I'm being executed");}, milisec);
    function stop() {
      clearInterval(myVar); 
    }
}
Module.exports = methods;
```

But I don't know how to refer to the function inside my methods.a on the `server.js` file

I've tried:

```
actions.a.stop()
```

but it doesn't work at all.. 
Is it even possible? Is there a way to execute the `clearInterval` in my `server.js`?

Appreciate your help

Comment: Please explain to us where your code runs and why the files are seperated. Are both files embedded in the same HTML document or is `server.js` running remotely on a NodeJS server?

Comment: both are embedded in the same HTML ! I'm working on a beaglebone and utilizing socket.io creating a server for executing the code..

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring myVar inside of methods.a(), making it's scope local to that function.  Try declaring myVar outside of the function.

Comment: well... seems it was all about global/local variables... :) thanks Larry, worked. declared myvar in the actions.js , and created an method for the function stop, called it inside the state == 0 if on the server.js